# Setting ExitCode in self-hosted F# script

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I am hosting the FSI.exe in my build tool ("[FAKE - F# Make](https://github.com/forki/FAKE)") and I need to set the ExitCode for FSI.exe from inside my fsx-script. Is this possible?

At the moment I am raising errors in the F# build script and this sets the exit code, but it also displays nasty exceptions and stackstraces in the build log.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
  Steffen

Comment: Environment.ExitCode <- 1 inside a script seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to [Alexander](http://twitter.com/controlflow) I now know the answer. I have to call `exit myExitCode`.